# Azure AD admin consent error for user logging into app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've created an App Registration in Azure that'll use the code grant flow to authenticate and authorize users. I've created a link for the first step of authenticating the user but I'm running into the following error for new users:

> AADSTS90094: This application requires application permissions to another application. Consent for application permissions can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.

The App Registration itself has the default delegated `User.Read` permission attached to it. I'm using the following uri as first step for the authentication:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=b2cd30fe-8109-4d71-afc7-e5bc2e468a69&
response_type=code&
code_challenge_method=S256&
code_challenge={challenge}&
redirect_uri={uri}&
scope=b2cd30fe-8109-4d71-afc7-e5bc2e468a69/.default
```

If I assign a custom scope to the App Registration with minimal information set to consent `Admin and users` and use that I have no issues. As example a scope named `test` and the above uri with scope as `b2cd30fe-8109-4d71-afc7-e5bc2e468a69/test`.

If I test both uri's for an existing user the only noticable difference in the resulting jwt token seems to be the scope:

> "scp": "User.Read",

> "scp": "User.Read test",

Why is the default scope triggering this error as it doesn't seem to do anything different?

Answer (score 0):

App registrations for Azure AD need to be Aplication.ReadWrite.All or Directory.ReadWrite.All`

If its a service principle or app registration you need to add, `Aplication.ReadWrite.All or Directory.ReadWrite.All` for that application under ms graph permissions for that app see link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-faq

I had a similar situation in Terraform and noticed on their docs it states the following: `When authenticated with a user principal, this resource requires one of the following directory roles: Application Administrator or Global Administrator`

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application#id

Cant put my hand on the MS Doc right now but when I changed my Azure AD User account to Application Admin Terraform worked to create the Azure Ad App in the Terraform CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. The application i mention above isn't used for requesting authentication itself. It's purely used for users to authenticate with to obtain a token with roles. So the permissions you listed shouldn't be needed as it's not used to make adjustments with the Graph API.